# javascript .replace() method not working properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the replace statement in javascript so that ultimately, i can create an array out of some data that is currently passed in a string.

I have the following javascript:

```
        console.log('data from server:' + server_rule_segements);
        //remove trailing ~
        server_rule_segements = server_rule_segements.substring(0,server_rule_segements.length-2); // stripping off trailing ~,
        console.log("1 - " + server_rule_segements); 
        server_rule_segements = server_rule_segements.replace("~,,", "~");
        console.log("2 - " + server_rule_segements);
```

Here's the results in the console:

```
data from server:Home Number,1234,1,no~,,Work Number,12342342,1,no~,,Work Number,12344412341234,1,no~, 
1 - Home Number,1234,1,no~,,Work Number,12342342,1,no~,,Work Number,12344412341234,1,no 
2 - Home Number,1234,1,no~Work Number,12342342,1,no~,,Work Number,12344412341234,1,no
```

What I'm wondering is why the replace command didn't replace all the instances of "~,,".
As you can see in the 2nd debug statement, there's still one there.. in what I'm calling "record 2".  I'm sure it's something simple that I've missed... but I can't see it right now.

As I test, I changed the code so that I call the replace method twice, like so:

```
server_rule_segements = server_rule_segements.replace("~,,", "~");
server_rule_segements = server_rule_segements.replace("~,,", "~");
```

and then it works. 
But I don't think I should have to do that.

Comment: Could be that the ~ or the commas are special characters. Try `replace("\~\,\,","\~")` and see if that works.

Comment: `replace` only replaces all occurrences if the first argument is a regexp with the `g` modifier. If it's a string, it just does one replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace method only replaces first instance, if you want all instances to be replaced use regular expressions. It would be easy because replace method also accepts regular expressions:

```
server_rule_segements = server_rule_segements.replace(/~,,/g, "~");
```

would do the trick. Notice the **"g"** flag means global replace. If you do not want to use regular expressions, use split immediately followed by a join,

```
server_rule_segements = server_rule_segements.split("~,,").join("~");
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace` only replaces the first occurance by default.
You need to change `server_rule_segements.replace("~,,", "~");` to `server_rule_segements.replace(/~,,/g, "~");`

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
server_rule_segements.replace("~,,", "~")
```

to

```
var re = new RegExp("~,,", 'g');
server_rule_segements.replace(re,"~")


Note i didn't run this code
```